# Updating JLabel with different values in a real time plot

Tags: java, swing, real-time, jfreechart, jlabel

I am making a real time graph with values that come in via serial communication.  I have the data coming in called my "Celsius" value.  I am displaying that on the GUI in a JLabel, so the value constantly changes.  The problem I am having is I want to have buttons that can change the value in the JLabel to Fahrenheit or back to Celsius.  So right now, I have my actionPerformed calling the updateTemp() method so it will update the JLabel right away when the program beings.  I have the code below for the 3 methods I think need to be changed around.

```
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
    updateTempC();
    final Double n = serial.x;
    series.addOrUpdate(new Millisecond(), n);
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if (e.getSource() == buttonF){
     degree.setText("degrees F");
     updateTempF();
   }

    if (e.getSource() == buttonC){
     degree.setText("degrees C");
     updateTempC();
    }
}

public void updateTempF(){
    int step1;
    int step2;
    int step3;
    String indata = serial.temp;
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(indata);
    step1 = temp*9;
    step2 = step1/5;
    step3 = step2 + 32;
    String indata1 = Integer.toString(step3);
    this.realtime.setText(indata1);
}

public void updateTempC(){
    String indata = serial.temp;
    this.realtime.setText(indata);
}
```

Right now when I press the JButton to change to Fahrenheit, it changes for a second but then goes right back to displaying Celsius because the graph is updated every second and the actionPerformed will go right back to calling the updateTempC().  I am wondering how, when I hit the button for Fahr. or Cels., it will change for the rest of the time.  THanks

Comment: Please edit your post above and re-post well formatted code. It is very hard to read and understand all left justified code. If you are asking us to put the effort into helping you, please put some effort into not making your question harder than it should be. The logic behind your solution is to not have the data display code set the JLabels, but rather just have the buttons change the JLabels.

Comment: Is `actionPerformed()` called when new data comes in from the serial _and_ called be the buttons, or is it called _only_ by you `JButtons`?

Comment: @Java, I have actionPerformed() being called when new data comes as well as called by the buttons at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a variable like `boolean fahrenheitTemp`. When `buttonF` is clicked, `fahrenheitTemp` will be set to `true`. When `buttonC` is clicked, `fahrenheitTemp` will be set to `false`. If `fahrenheitTemp` is `true`, call `updateTempF()`, else call `updateTempC()`. (Also, you have a `Object source` variable, but you never use it.)

Try modifying your `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` to something like this:

```
boolean fahrenheitTemp = false;
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {
    if (fahrenheitTemp) {
        updateTempF();
    } else {
        updateTempC();
    }
    final Double n = serial.x;
    series.addOrUpdate(new Millisecond(), n);
    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == buttonF) {
        degree.setText("degrees F");
        fahrenheitTemp = true;
        updateTempF();
    } else if (source == buttonC) {
        degree.setText("degrees C");
        fahrenheitTemp = false;
        updateTempC();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for the response @Java.  It worked great.  Thanks for helping me figure that out it was quite annoying and seemed pretty simple to solve that problem I just couldn't wrap my head around it.  Thanks also for letting me know about that Object source variable.  Cheers